# External IP is not get visible on my compute engine dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

External IP does not get visible for my one of the compute engine

Answer (score 0):

You may have not reserved an external static IP. You can do it through the Google console using an ephemeral IP address[1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) or assignnating one custom IP address mannually.[2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance)
If your issue is more related to the Google Console UI, try to check if there is a reserved external IP address for your particular VM instance by using the Google Shell and the following command:

> $ gcloud compute instances list

You will need to provide more details about whats exactly is your issue.

---